# How do I prove correctness of my algorithm that finds a pair of integers in an array that have a sum of 0?

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms, correctness-proof, search, program-correctness

I have designed an algorithm (up to making a pseudocode) that accepts a sorted array as input and finds in $O(n)$ time if there's a pair of elements (integers) in the array that have a sum zero.

What my algorithm basically does is:

1. set index $i$ = 0
2. set index $j$ = length(array) - 1
3. while $i<j$ : if $a[i]+a[j]=0$ then it returns the pair, if $a[i]+a[j]<0$ it does $i++$ and if $a[i]+a[j]>0$ it does $j--$.
4. if at some point $i=j$ it stops and returns that the pair was not found.

I read that when making an algorithm you need to prove its correctness, but the methods that I've read don't seem fitting to me. I can't think how to use induction - for example - past the "assume it works for $n=m$" because I feel like I'd be explaining how the algorithm works again.

Can someone indicate how I can prove the correctness?

Comment: Merge sort uses $\mathcal{O}(n\log n)$ time, not $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$ time.

Comment: @Nathaniel Yes, my bad, the sorting shouldn't be taken into account for the complexity, I'll edit my question so it is correct.

Comment: I think there is a confusion in the third item: you write "if $i+j = 0$", but it should be "if $a[i] + a[j] = 0$", and same thing for the other comparisons.

Comment: @Nathaniel You are absolutely right. I'm sorry that's what in my pseudocode as well, it's just late, I've been working all day and made mistakes. Thanks for bringing them up.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can prove this property using a [loop invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_invariant). Naming the array $a$ and $n = |a|$, consider the following property $(P)$:

> There exist $(k,\ell)\in \{0, …, n-1\}, k\neq \ell$, such that $a[k] + a[\ell] = 0$ if and only if There exist $(k,\ell)\in \{i, …, j\}, k\neq \ell$, such that $a[k] + a[\ell] = 0$

Meaning that the two indices you are searching for are necessarily between $i$ and $j$ (included).

Then, the property $(P)$ is a loop invariant of your algorithm:

- it is trivially true before the loop;
- it stays true at each step of the loop, considering all three cases (proof left to you).

Now, you can use this loop invariant to prove the correctness of your algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I've never used the loop invariant method, so I wasn't familiar with it. :)

Comment: It is one of the most elementary method for proof: induction for recursion, loop invariant for loops.

Comment: I have probably come across it a CS class, but we rarely focused on proofs which is why it was weird to me that I read we have to prove algorithms on top of explaining how they work, even if logically they make sense. Thanks for the boost, I'll definitely read more on algo proofs moving forward!

Comment: There is an important ingredient missing: proving that the algorithm does terminate.

Comment: @YvesDaoust you are right, but since OP said they already had computed the complexity, I assumed termination was not the difficult part.

Comment: The question is "how I can prove the correctness?"

Comment: @YvesDaoust you are right, but since OP said they already had computed the complexity, I assumed termination was not the difficult part.